# proguard and jdom error compling android APK

Tags: java, android, proguard, geonames

I can't create release of android app because i'm using geonames and jdom. jdom gives this error:

```
[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath$NSContext: can't find superclass or interface org.jaxen.SimpleNamespaceContext

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.JDOMException: can't find referenced class java.rmi.RemoteException

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.JDOMException: can't find referenced class java.rmi.RemoteException

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.BaseXPath

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.JaxenException

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.SimpleVariableContext

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.jdom.JDOMXPath

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.jdom.JDOMXPath

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.BaseXPath

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.BaseXPath

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.BaseXPath

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.BaseXPath

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.BaseXPath

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.BaseXPath

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.SimpleVariableContext

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.BaseXPath

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.BaseXPath

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.jdom.JDOMXPath

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.JaxenException

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.JaxenException

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.JaxenException

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.JaxenException

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath$NSContext: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.SimpleNamespaceContext

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath$NSContext: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.SimpleNamespaceContext

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath$NSContext: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.SimpleNamespaceContext

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] Warning: there were 25 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)

[2013-07-02 19:52:56 - <appname>]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDOM versions 1.x are not officially supported on Android (though they may work). [JDOM 2.x versions *are* supported](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/wiki/JDOM2-and-Android) (with some limitations).

The issue you have is that you are not porting the [jaxen library](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/) to your android system though. You need to ensure that your project includes the jazen jar otherwise your class dependencies for JDOM XPaths will not work.

Note that in JDOM 2.x there is a [better API for XPath queries](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/wiki/JDOM2-Feature-XPath-Upgrade).